# Finalizar Activity al pasar a otra Activity clickeando un fragment

Tags: java, android, activity

Estoy programando en Android Studio mi duda es que tengo un Fragment en la parte inferior donde aparecerán diferentes opciones, pero cada vez que hago click en algun boton del fragment, este me abre una nueva activity (no sé cómo, soy nuevo) ya que **cuando doy atrás me sale la misma y así**, si hago click 4 veces el boton que abre el activity, luego doy 4 veces back me saldrá la misma Activity, mi duda es: ¿si tengo que finalizar la activity, dónde doy click antes de abrir la siguiente?, y si es así ¿cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que comentas amigo, si quieres que ese comportamiento en un **Fragment** no te ocurra en el evento ***onClickListener*** de tu botón o view que hayas pulsado, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v ->
{
    // v es el view
    // esto es en el fragment, al hacer esto cuando vayas hacia la nueva actividad
    // y desees regresar a esta, no podras, pues la vas a destruir, tu app navegara
    // hacia el destino que le tengas programado o saldra de tu app

    // logica de tu evento
    ...

    startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
    requireActivity().finish();
});
```

Eso es todo amigo, segun lo que preguntas esto soluciona tus problemas, en caso de ser otro el problema edita tu pregunta. Salu2